# Join SQL query not giving desired result

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have separate queries with me as follows:

```
SELECT c.id 
FROM   claim c, 
       company co, 
       customer cu 
WHERE  c.company_id = co.id 
       AND c.customer_id = cu.id 
       AND co.company_code = 'LTO' 
       AND cu.customer_no = '021540' 
       AND c.invoice_number IS NOT NULL 
       AND c.invoice_date IS NULL 
       AND c.invoice_number = '20170331' 

SELECT Sum(price) 
FROM   replaced_part 
WHERE  claim_id IN ( 628099, 674047, 1182523, 1282549, 
                     1479834, 1480585, 1487452, 1515238 ); 

SELECT Sum(price) 
FROM   allowance 
WHERE  claim_id IN ( 628099, 674047, 1182523, 1282549, 
                     1479834, 1480585, 1487452, 1515238 );
```

I was trying to group together all the above queries into one using sql equi join as follows:

```
select  co.company_Code,
        cu.customer_No, 
        c.invoice_Number, 
        sum(r.price), 
        sum(a.price) 
FROM    claim c INNER JOIN company co ON c.COMPANY_ID=co.ID 
                INNER JOIN customer cu ON c.CUSTOMER_ID=cu.ID 
                INNER JOIN replaced_part r ON r.claim_id=c.id 
                INNER JOIN allowance a ON a.claim_id = c.id
WHERE   co.company_code = 'LTO' and cu.customer_no='021540' and 
        c.INVOICE_NUMBER is not null and c.INVOICE_DATE is null and
        c.INVOICE_NUMBER='20170331' 
GROUP BY co.company_Code, cu.customer_No, c.invoice_Number
```

But I am not getting the desired result(Query execute successfully but the sum is incorrect) as I am getting after running the 3 separate queries defined above... What is the problem here in my query created using equi join??

Relationship between tables are claim ->(one to one) -> company ->(one to one) -> customer ->(one to many) ->Replaced_Part ->(one to many) -> allowance

Comment: Rewrite using proper ANSI joins (INNER JOIN with ON clause) instead of the ancient non-standard syntax of just listing tables and then filtering with WHERE clauses for starters.

Comment: Use one`CTE` for each query, and then join the results

Comment: Query Rewritten using INNER JOIN

Comment: "c.INVOICE_NUMBER is not null" is pointless when you also have "c.INVOICE_NUMBER='20170331'". So what is the issue?

Comment: Issue is incorrect value in SUM.. Let me try to explain a little bit 1 claim has 2 Replace Parts and 3 Allowance.. If I will remove one of the join either replaced_part or allowance then sum is correct but if I will put these together it is not giving the correct result

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use left join for Replaced_Part and allowance

```
select  co.company_Code
   , cu.customer_No
   , c.invoice_Number
   , (SELECT sum(r.price) FROM replaced_part r WHERE r.claim_id = c.id)
   , (SELECT sum(a.price) FROM allowance a WHERE a.claim_id = c.id)
FROM    claim c 
INNER JOIN company co 
    ON c.COMPANY_ID=co.ID 
INNER JOIN customer cu 
    ON c.CUSTOMER_ID=cu.ID     
WHERE   co.company_code = 'LTO' 
AND cu.customer_no='021540' 
AND c.INVOICE_DATE is null 
AND c.INVOICE_NUMBER='20170331' 
GROUP BY co.company_Code
, cu.customer_No
, c.invoice_Number
```

Comment: No change in the result wendy as using left join for alowance and replace part doesn't have any effect in the output

Answer (score 0):

try to use temporary table, combine all the tables and make a temporary table, then fire your conditions on that table.

Example :

```
select  co.company_Code,
        cu.customer_No, 
        c.invoice_Number, 
        sum(r.price), 
        sum(a.price) 
into #temp from (claim c
                INNER JOIN company co ON c.COMPANY_ID=co.ID 
                INNER JOIN customer cu ON c.CUSTOMER_ID=cu.ID 
                INNER JOIN replaced_part r ON r.claim_id=c.id 
                INNER JOIN allowance a ON a.claim_id = c.id
```

and then use your conditions on #temp. like

```
select * from #temp 
WHERE   company_code = 'LTO' and customer_no='021540' and 
        INVOICE_NUMBER is not null and INVOICE_DATE is null and
        INVOICE_NUMBER='20170331' 
GROUP BY company_Code, customer_No, invoice_Number
```

Hope this will work for you.